# Adding subtitles to video fails with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, subtitles

I am trying to add a subtitle to a video using ffmpeg and a `.srt` file.
Using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i videopath.mp4 -i subtitlefilepath.srt -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k -strict -2 videooutput.mp4
```

`.srt` file looks like

```
1
00:00:00,30-->00:00:05,30
Sample sub title for video
```

What is that 30 after `duration`?

Output:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-12-11-3b28564 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers  built on Jan 22 2014 13:22:00 with gcc 4.6 (GCC) 20120106 (peelease)  configuration: --arch=arm --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --prefix=../build --sysroot=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm --extra-cflags=' -I/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -I../libmp3lame/include -I../libx264/include -DANDROID -marm -march=armv6 ' --extra-ldflags=' -L/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib -L../libmp3lame/lib -L../libx264/lib' --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avfilter --enable-decoders --enable-demuxers --enable-encoders --enable-filters --enable-indevs --enable-network --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-swscale --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100  
libavcodec     55. 48.102 / 55. 48.102  
libavformat    55. 25.101 / 55. 25.101  
libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102  
libavfilter     4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100  
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101  
libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104  
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141022_125926.mp4':  
    Metadata:    
        major_brand     : isom    
        minor_version   : 0    
        compatible_brands: isom3gp4    
        creation_time   : 2014-10-22 07:29:39  
        Duration: 00:00:08.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11752 kb/s  
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 1280x720, 11758 kb/s, 29.33 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)    
    Metadata:      
        rotate          : 90      
        creation_time   : 2014-10-22 07:29:39      
        handler_name    : VideoHandle    
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 60 kb/s (default)    
    Metadata:      
        creation_time   : 2014-10-22 07:29:39      
        handler_name    : SoundHandle

Input #1, srt, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/subtitle.srt':  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A    
Stream #1:0: Subtitle: subrip

[libx264 @ 0x11cf050] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON[libx264 @ 0x11cf050] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x11cf050] 264 - core 140 r2377 1ca7bb9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0

Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/VideoOverLay/videooverlay1413965066659.mp4':  
    Metadata:    
        major_brand     : isom    
        minor_version   : 0    
        compatible_brands: isom3gp4    
        encoder         : Lavf55.25.101    
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)    
    Metadata:      
        rotate          : 90      
        creation_time   : 2014-10-22 07:29:39      
        handler_name    : VideoHandle    
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)    
    Metadata:      
        creation_time   : 2014-10-22 07:29:39      
        handler_name    : SoundHandle

Stream mapping:  
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)  
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> aac)

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.47 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.91 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=    3 fps=1.2 q=23.0 size=      38kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 311.9kbits/s    
frame=    6 fps=1.9 q=22.0 size=      7
10-22 13:35:08.365: D/dalvikvm(1754): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1968K, 26% free 16486K/22120K, paused 14ms+6ms, total 59ms
10-22 13:35:08.365: I/exit code >>>>>>>>..(1754): 0
10-22 13:35:08.365: I/exit code >>>>>>>>..(1754): 0
```

I can't see any subtitles on the video. Where's the problem?

Comment: Can you please take care to format the output properly next time? In one line it's hard to read. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with the output file? Do the subtitles not show up when you play it or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not telling ffmpeg to use the subtitles. With multiple inputs ffmpeg will only map one, IIRC:

```
Stream mapping:  
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)  
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> aac)
```

So try something like:

```
ffmpeg -i videopath.mp4 -i subtitlefilepath.srt \
-c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
-ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k -strict -2 \
-c:s mov_text -map 0 -map 1 \
videooutput.mp4
```

This would copy the subtitles as-is and map the input video (`-map 0`) and subtitle file (`-map 1`) to the output. You should see something like this:

```
Stream mapping:  
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)  
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> aac)
    Stream #1:0 -> #1:0 (srt -> mov_text)
```

You could also use the [`subtitles` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#subtitles-1) to hardcode subs. For that you need to compile ffmpeg version with `libass` though, which is not the case for the one you're using.

Comment: @slhck One more thing can i add subtitle wherever i need ? because its coming below video. Can i show it on video, means at the center ?.

Comment: @slhck Sub title are not displaying when I play video on player like Vlc, Es media player. It can be seen only on default player of device.

Comment: @Gururaj Softsubs in MP4 may not be supported widely by players and devices. Do you specifically need to use MP4, or will MKV also work for you as the output container? VLC showed the subtitles for my test, but I had to manually select them: Subtitle > Sub Track > Track 1.

Comment: @Gururaj With SRT, you cannot force the position of the subtitles. This is handled by the player only.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thanks for the reply :). For me same thing, Vlc showed me the sub title by setting manually. Yes i want to go with only mp4 only. As you and slhck said we cant force any media player to show the subtitle isnt it? Or is there any other way?.

Comment: @Gururaj Then you'll either have to put up with the limitations of MP4 softsubs or use [hardsubs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20burn%20subtitles%20into%20the%20video) which require you to re-encode the video.